# Backing up a MySQL/MariaDB database via ZFS snapshots without errors

Tags: mysql, zfs, mariadb, snapshot

So I am using zrepl to take snapshots of my production machine and replicate them to a backup server. This also includes MariaDB, it's in it's own dataset with `recordsize=16k`

I've been testing the snapshots today to see if I could mount one snapshot on the backup server to dump one table to file but whenever I start MariaDB I always get errors like:

```
[Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=xxxxxx
[Note] InnoDB: To recover: LSN xxxxxx
InnoDB: At LSN: 15347562372082: unable to open file ./<dbname>/#sql-ib93859.ibd for tablespace 93856
```

Because the backup machine only has slow HDDs it takes forever to recover and actually boot up MariaDB. Not 100% about DB integrity at this point.

I am running `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` before the snapshot and `UNLOCK TABLES` after. However my mysql log dir is in a different ZFS dataset (recordsize=128k) as recommended by OpenZFS and many others.

I also use `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0`.

Could my issue be that `ib_logfile0` is in a different dataset? Meaning `zrepl` probably runs `FLUSH TABLES` per dataset. So between the two snapshots it could have unlocked the tables for a split second and written some stuff to the logfile?

If so. Would `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` fix it or is the only option moving `ib_logfile0` back into the same dataset as the MariaDB datadir?

In case of the latter, are there any performance drawbacks of having the log on recordsize 16k versus 128k?